# Displaying '{}, {}' in my GUI ListBox on Tkinter when inputting details to SQLite database

Tags: python, sqlite, tkinter

My Backend code looks like this
Where I created a function so that I could add new users to database where I would like a default input of the following; created_at=str(created_at),updated_at = "",status,("1"),verified="1",language="EN" in the function :

```
import sqlite3 
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd


db="practice.db"

# Current time
now = datetime.now()
created_at = now.strftime("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")

def addCustRec(customer_id, gender, dob,created_at=str(created_at),updated_at = "",status=("1"),verified="1",language="EN"):
    conn=sqlite3.connect(db)
    cur=conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO customer VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)",(customer_id,sex(gender),dob,status,verified,language,created_at,updated_at))
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()
    view()
```

My front end code looks like this:

```
OPTIONS = ["None","Male", "Female"]

class Customer:
    

    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        self.root.title("Name of window")
        #self.root.geometry("1350x7500+0+0")

        customer_id = StringVar()
        gender = StringVar()
        dob = StringVar()
        created_at = StringVar()
        status = StringVar()
        verified = StringVar()
        language = StringVar()

        #======================================================= Functions ==================================================================#
        def addData():
            if(len(customer_id.get()) !=0):
                Back_end_GUI.addCustRec(customer_id.get(), gender.get(), dob.get(),status.get(),verified.get(),language.get(),created_at.get())
                DataFrame.delete(0,END)
                DataFrame.insert(END,(customer_id.get(), gender.get(), dob.get(),status.get(),verified.get(),language.get(),created_at.get()))
        #========================================================= Window ===================================================================#
        window = Frame(self.root)
        window.grid()
        #================================================ List/dataframe Box & ScrollBar widget ==============================================#
        # ListBox
        DataFrame = Listbox(window, height=10, width=50)
        DataFrame.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>',CustomerRec)
        DataFrame.grid(row=1,column=3, rowspan=6, columnspan=2)

        # Scrollbar
        scrollbar= Scrollbar(window)
        scrollbar.grid(row=1,column=2,sticky='ns',rowspan=6)

        DataFrame.configure(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
        scrollbar.configure(command=DataFrame.yview)

        #=================================================== Labels and Entry widgets =======================================================#
        # Customer
        self.customer_id = Label(window, text="Customer ID:")
        self.customer_id.grid(row=1,column=0)
        self.customer_id=Entry(window,textvariable=customer_id)
        self.customer_id.grid(row=1,column=1)

        # Gender - Drop down menu
        self.gender = Label(window, text="Sex:")
        self.gender.grid(row=2,column=0)
        gender.set(OPTIONS[0]) # Default Value
        self.gender = OptionMenu(window, gender, *OPTIONS)
        self.gender.grid(row =2, column=1)

        #Year of birth
        self.dob = Label(window, text="Year of Birth:")
        self.dob.grid(row=3,column=0)
        self.dob=Entry(window,textvariable=dob)
        self.dob.grid(row=3,column=1)
        #========================================================== Button widgets ============================================================#
        self.b1=Button(window, text="Add New", width = 12, command=addData)
        self.b1.grid(row=4, column=0)
```

My problem is, when adding new users, how do I replace the '{}{}' with the actual default variables form the 'AddCust' function?
[image]

If you want to create the database:

```
def customerData():
    conn=sqlite3.connect(databasename)
    cur=conn.cursor()
    cur.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS customer (customer_id VARCHAR(200) PRIMARY KEY,gender VARCHAR(200),dob VARCHAR(200),status   VARCHAR(200),verified VARCHAR(200),language VARCHAR(200),created_at VARCHAR(200),updated_at VARCHAR(200)")
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()
```

Comment: The code you posted doesn't have a listbox in it. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Ive edited and added the ListBox my bad! I've also added the query for the schema at the bottom where cur.execute is

Comment: @acosta1556 put your code together such that we can run your code directly by pasting it in our editor